# Are there any planes where time passes more quickly?

Tags: dnd-5e, planes, time

Are there any planes in 5e where time passes more quickly?

I was just wondering because I was thinking of providing a situation where my players travel to a different plane, and they come back to find that it's 100 years later. I know I could homebrew it, but I want to know if there is anything official so I don't "DM BS" my players.

Comment: Doesn't necessarily have to be the plane itself, could be a portal error: Related explanation - [Is there any precedent for time distortion when traveling to other planes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67096/is-there-any-precedent-for-time-distortion-when-traveling-to-other-planes)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### This can happen in the Feywild

The DMG has a section on planes, and the Feywild in particular has the possibility of a [Time Warp](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/creating-a-multiverse#TimeWarp) (DMG p. 50) occurring (emphasis mine):

> Time Warp
>
> While time seems to pass normally in the Feywild, characters might spend a day there and realize, upon leaving the plane, that less or more time has elapsed everywhere else in the multiverse.
>
> Whenever a creature or group of creatures leaves the Feywild after spending at least 1 day on that plane, you can **choose a time change that works best for your campaign**, if any, or roll on the Feywild Time Warp table.

Besides suggesting you simply choose the exact value of the time warp, the included table of possibilities for how the time is warped has an option for "Days become years" which seems to be in line with what you want.

Comment: So im wondering. Would the manuals time go down? I just don't want to give my players a way to easily get 30 dex and con

Comment: @user60792 Manuals time? If you mean the magic item manuals that increase ability scores then if left anywhere else in the multiverse, yes, as the quote says. As for gaming this, note that this Time Warp effect is mostly up to the DM. Just as a visit to the Feywild can bring them a lot of time into the future, it can also bring them but a few minutes so this isn't really something that can be exploited this way unless you want it to.

Comment: @user60792 Plus, one day in Feywild = a lot of time for the manual to be stolen on the Prime Material Plane, right?

Comment: Ok. I just didn't want them to be able to argue that since going to the fey wild sent them far into the future, it would always. Its just that I would probably do that so I wanted to make sure it couldn't.

Comment: @user60792 Feywild time is unpredictable to anyone but most powerful fey. Or is it? You'll never know! ;) it says in the DMG that it's random or what fits the story, just show them that if they argue.